# Using same memory session when calling a CLR from SQL Server

Tags: c#, session, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I hvae the following situation:

- I have built a CLR in C# which has a function which gets two Strings, one represents table name, and the other represent a query to perform, and it perform the query and insert it's results into a new table with the given name.
- From SQL Server 2012, I want to perform the CLR on two different queries (represented as NVARCHAR in SQLSERVER) into two different tables.
- I have another NVARCHAR which contains declerations of variables, e.g: `Declare @a INT SELECT @a=a From...`. This is a long String which contains unknown number of parameters, and there is no restrictions on it. And, most important, the declarations are dynamic/random so they might not be the same if I use them the same way twice.
- The two queries uses the parameters from before, but I need them to use the same static values.
- Until now, I added first query to parameters and sent to CLR, then added second query to parameters and sent to CLR again and got two tables. Problem is - each time CLR is performed, parameters get different values.

Somehow, I need to find a way to run the parameters once, and use them with the two queries.
I tried `EXEC (@Parameters)` and then using CLR on both queries, but I guess that for each call for the CLR a new memory stack is open, so it is not familiar with the already declared variables.

I need to find a way to make the parameters available for both queries using the CLR.

I searched for a solution which does not start a new session when calling the CLR and then maybe the memory will be kept for both queries.

Any other elegant solution is welcomed!

Comment: Can't you merge the 2 queries? If they're using the same parameters and the queries are executed one after the other, seems that whatever you do in it could be merged

Comment: No, unfortunately i can't, each query must be sent separately to the CLR because the result of each of them must be inserted to a different table.

Comment: Ok, then you could make another CLR method that takes 3 parameters (2 table names and the parameters) and then merge the 2 queries, seems the simplest way